# GIt GUI (SourceTree, Github for Mac, Tower) apps show all files as modified

Tags: macos, git, github

We have a local development server set up, with Git and whatnot installed. The 
server is mounted in Finder, which makes it believe it is "local" (from a GUI perspective).

I can SSH into the server, run a git status and it returns the results I expect - only modified files showing up as modified, new, deleted etc.

When I add the repo to any mac Git GUI app (SourceTree, Github for Mac, Tower) or even the Git plugin for sublime it lists every file as modified and wants me to stage and commit the files.

This happens with any git repository on the server. If I run a `git init` do the initial commit with one of the apps, then they all behave fine.

Is there a git repo setting i need to set via command line for these apps to behave? I'vr had a google round but can;t find anyone with a similar problem.

[Before any just says "*use the command line*" we have some designers who tweak code but have no experience with the terminal. I plan to slowly train them but find it easier if they understand the basics of git before exposing them to the black and white world!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the Mac Apps required the files to be `755` read/write permissions. We had them set as `644`.

Changing the permissions and committing seems to cheer the apps up to behave correctly.

The other option is to change the git repo to not track filemode changes.

You can set the global config setting to false

`git config --global core.filemode false`

Or set it on a repo by repo basis

`git config core.filemode false`

---

The error i was getting in Tower was:

*"File mode changed from 100644 (Regular) to 100775 (Executable)"*